# Junit that an annotation is on a method

Tags: java, junit

Sometimes developers on my team will comment out @Async annotations if they are debugging locally, for easier debugging.  I want to ensure that they do not forget to uncomment the commented @Async tags when they are done.  Thus is there a way to verify that an annotation is on a method call via a junit?

Something like this would be an example of what I am looking for:

```
//@Async 
public void doAsync(){
    logic();
}
```

since the @Async is commented out I would like a junit to return an error similar to "doAsync (aka method name) should have an @Async annotation."

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to use reflection to verify the annotation was there.

```
Method m = classType.getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
Annotation a = m.getAnnotation(Async.class);
assertTrue(a.annotationType() == Async.class);
```

Thanks,
Brian